# The word "await" used instead of "Wait for" in many dictionary meanings and thesaurus synonyms

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality-in-context

Why the word  "Await" preferred to any dictionary meaning or thesaurus synonyms even though there are innumerable synonyms in thesaurus.

The front cover of a magazine published:[ a small magazine,economist,given free with India-Today magazine] perhaps in 2003

> "ABHIJIT BAGCHI SANYAL [MY NAME] THE WORLD **AWAITS** YOUR DECISION"

Why the word "await" chosen instead of any other dictionary meaning or synonym?

Answer (score 1):

As it looks, that seems to be a title. And, as usual, titles have to be as short as possible (see [**headlinese**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)).

So the editor had to choose between:

> wait for

and

> await

As a plus, "await" sounds a bit "cooler" than "wait (for)", since it is used less.

Comment: @lambie-await verb wait for.synonyms-[1] Peter was awaiting news[2]many dangers await them."Wait for" as we all know-We are waiting for our morning tea.[from oxford dictionary and thesaurus] user26375

Answer (score 0):

**await** and **wait for** are the same thing.

**await** is **more formal** and **used in written text** and formal speech.

"We await your decision, Sir." [to a person in a hierarchy, above the speaker.]

Therefore, it is better in a title, formal speech and some writing.

Also, we generally say: wait for in normal speech.

This difference of style is probably not in most dictionaries. [I have not checked that specifically.]

Answer (score 0):

We do not await a person but await his arrival or decision. But we wait for a person and wait for our morning cup of tea to be served. Even though in accordance with any dictionary "Await" means"Wait for". So there is nothing wrong in the front cover of the magazine "The world awaits your decision."

Comment: While "wait for" is more usual than "await", such sentences as  "He awaited his tea with eagerness.", or  "Joan awaited Mrs Fenster with bated breath." When there is emotional laoding on the waiting process, "await" may be more often used. In any case, "await" can be used in any context where "wait for" is normally used.